# sqlserver change date based condition current date

Tags: sql-server, date, conditional-statements

this is my query :

```
select distinct idArticulo, costoProveedor ,min (fechaRecepcion) as Desde,
max(fechaRecepcion) as Hasta
into #tmp_precios_cambios_historia
from Tbl_NetSuite_Articulos tnsa 
group by   idArticulo, costoProveedor 

select *
from #tmp_precios_cambios_historia
where idArticulo like 'PU_886412/02_1_1'
group by idArticulo, costoProveedor, Desde, Hasta
```

And I get this :

| idArticulo | costoProveedor | Desde | Hasta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PU_886412/02_1_1 | 537.8000 | 2021-06-03 15:05:00.000 | 2021-06-09 14:32:00.000 |
| PU_886412/02_1_1 | 626.1500 | 2021-06-11 13:47:00.000 | 2021-07-01 13:02:00.000 |
| PU_886412/02_1_1 | 659.6100 | 2021-09-17 15:46:00.000 | 2022-03-15 17:44:00.000 |

I need to replace last date from "Hasta" column (2022-03-15 17:44:00.000). If it's < than getdate() by current date (getdate())...I don´t know if there is some window function ...I tried with conditionals, but I couldn´t solve it...It's an example with one article, but I have more than 1MM articles, so I nned the same for each article...compare las "Hasta" Date vs today and replace it...
Could someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: `case when max(fechaRecepcion) >= getdate() then max(fechaRecepcion) else getdate()`

Comment: @shawnt00 Hi, it´s wrong...by this way u always get current date...that´s not what I need...

Comment: @shawnt00 :

I need to replace last date from "Hasta" column (2022-03-15 17:44:00.000). If it's < than getdate() by current date (getdate())

Comment: Per article: `case when max(max(fechaRecepcion)) over (partition by idArticulo) = max(fechaRecepcion) and max(fechaRecepcion) < getdate() then getdate() else max(fechaRecepcion) end`